# Trying to reload a function on click of an image

Tags: json

I have a JSON file and I am trying to reload a function inside my code but I cant seem to get it to work. After you click an item from the page, it shows the items contents etc. At the bottom I have a similar product for each item. What i want to do is reload the page on click of the similar product image and show the correct item on the page but I cant seem to make it work. Any help or suggestions is very much appreciated thanks!

I included a working example below please visit the codepen link:

http://codepen.io/tcarp/pen/aBPLqX

```
  'use strict';

  $.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: '',
    success: function(json){

      //check for window hash and display product category  
      var categoryHash = window.location.hash;
      switch(categoryHash) 
      {
          case '#tomatoes':
               displayTomatoes(); 
               break;
          default:
               displayAll();
               break;
      }

      //display product category based on click
      $("#tomatoes").click(function(event){
         displayTomatoes(); 
            event.preventDefault();
            window.location.hash = '#tomatoes'; 
      }); 
      $("#displayall").click(function(event){
         displayAll();
      });

      //display all products function 
      function displayAll() {
          var categoryImage = '';

          $.each(json, function (i, item) {
                     categoryImage += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">' + '<a href="#"' + 'class="showProduct"' + 'data-itempageurl="' + item.itemFullUPC + '"' + 'data-itemgmo="' + item.itemGMOFree + '"' + 'data-itembpa="' + item.itemBPAFree + '"' + 'data-itemgluten="' + item.itemGlutenFree + '"' + 'data-itemlowsodium="' + item.itemLowSodium + '"' + 'data-itemorganic="' + item.itemOrganic + '"' + 'data-itemimage="' + item.imageURL + '"' + 'data-itemname="' + item.itemName + '"' + 'data-itemoz="' + item.itemPackSize + '"' + 'data-itemdescription="' + item.itemDescription + '"' + 'data-itemupc="' + item.itemFullUPC + '">' + '<img class="img-responsive img-hover productImagesCategory" src="' + item.imageURL + '">' + '<h3>' + item.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
          });

          $('#imagesCategoryProducts').hide().html(categoryImage).fadeIn('slow');

          //show individual product function on click
          $(".showProduct").click(function(event){

             //hide all current products
             $('#productCategories').hide();

             //get passed data from other function
             var clickedItemName = '<h1>' + $(this).data('itemname') + '</h1>';
             var clickedItemUPC = $(this).data('itemupc');
             var clickedItemOZ = $(this).data('itemoz')
             var clickedItemDescription = '<p>' + $(this).data('itemdescription') + '</p>';
             var clickedItemImage = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block" src="' + $(this).data('itemimage') + '">';
             var clickedItemGluten = $(this).data('itemgluten');
             var clickedItemBPA = $(this).data('itembpa');
             var clickedItemGMO = $(this).data('itemgmo');
             var clickedItemLowSodium = $(this).data('itemlowsodium');
             var clickedItemOrganic = $(this).data('itemorganic');
             var clickedItemPageURL = $(this).data('itempageurl');

             //check if clicked data equals correct item
             $.each(json, function (i, item) {
               if (item.itemName === clickedItemName) {
                  clickedItemName 
               }
               if (item.itemFullUPC === clickedItemUPC) {
                  clickedItemUPC
               }
               if (item.itemPackSize === clickedItemOZ) {
                  clickedItemOZ
               }
               if (item.itemDescription === clickedItemDescription) {
                  clickedItemDescription
               }
               if (item.imageURL === clickedItemImage) {
                  clickedItemImage
               }
               if (item.itemGlutenFree === clickedItemGluten) {
                  clickedItemGluten
               }
               if (item.itemBPAFree === clickedItemBPA) {
                  clickedItemBPA
               }
               if (item.itemGMOFree === clickedItemGMO) {
                  clickedItemGMO
               }
               if (item.itemOrganic === clickedItemOrganic) {
                  clickedItemOrganic
               }
               if (item.itemLowSodium === clickedItemLowSodium) {
                  clickedItemLowSodium
               }

               //assign window hash to each product
               if (item.itemFullUPC === clickedItemPageURL) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  clickedItemPageURL = clickedItemPageURL.replace(/\s/g, '');
                  window.location.hash = clickedItemPageURL; 
               }
             });

               //remove extra characters from UPC
               var originalUPC = clickedItemUPC;
               var strippedUPC = '<h2>' + originalUPC.slice(1, -1); + '</h2>';

               //remove characters after slash from Pack Size
               var originalPackSize = clickedItemOZ;
               var strippedPackSize = '<h2>' + clickedItemOZ.substring(clickedItemOZ.lastIndexOf("/") + 1); + '</h2>';

               //show individual product information
               $('#productSocialShare').show();
               $('#individualProduct').show();
               $('#relatedProducts').show();   

               //append product information to appropriate DIV
               $('#productTitle').html(clickedItemName); 
               $('#productUPC').html(strippedUPC);
               $('#productOZ').html(strippedPackSize);
               $('#productDescription').html(clickedItemDescription);
               $('#productImage').html(clickedItemImage);

               //check if gluten free is true and show image
               if (clickedItemGluten == "Y") {
                   clickedItemGluten = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="http://www.cento.com/DEV/images/misc/gluten_free_test.jpg">';
                   $('#productGlutenFree').html(clickedItemGluten);
                   $('#productGlutenFree').show();
               } else { 
                   $('#productGlutenFree').hide();
               }

               //check if bpa free is true and show image
               if (clickedItemBPA == "Y") {
                   clickedItemBPA = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="http://www.cento.com/DEV/images/misc/bpa_free_test.jpg">';
                   $('#productBPAFree').html(clickedItemBPA);
                   $('#productBPAFree').show();
               } else { 
                   $('#productBPAFree').hide();
               }

               //check if gmo free is true and show image
               if (clickedItemGMO == "Y") {
                   clickedItemGMO = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="http://www.cento.com/DEV/images/misc/gmo_test.jpg">';
                   $('#productGMOFree').html(clickedItemGMO);
                   $('#productGMOFree').show();
               } else { 
                   $('#productGMOFree').hide();
               }

               //check if organic is true and show image
               if (clickedItemOrganic == "Y") {
                   clickedItemOrganic = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="http://www.cento.com/DEV/images/misc/organic_test.jpg">';
                   $('#productOrganic').html(clickedItemOrganic);
                   $('#productOrganic').show();
               } else { 
                   $('#productOrganic').hide();
               }

               //check if low sodium is true and show image
               if (clickedItemLowSodium == "Y") {
                   clickedItemLowSodium = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="http://www.cento.com/DEV/images/misc/low_sodium_test.jpg">';
                   $('#productLowSodium').html(clickedItemLowSodium);
                   $('#productLowSodium').show();
               } else { 
                   $('#productLowSodium').hide();
               } 

               //show random recipe for each item
               var url = 'http://www.cento.com/DEV/recipes.json';
               $.getJSON(url, function(json) {          
                    var randomRecipe = json[Math.floor(Math.random() * json.length)];
                    randomRecipe = '<div>' + '<a href="' + randomRecipe.recipePageURL + '">' + '<img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="' + randomRecipe.recipeImageCategoryURL + '">' + '</a>' + '<a href="' + randomRecipe.recipePageURL +'">' + '<h3 class="similarProductSubCategoryImgCaption">' + randomRecipe.recipeName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
                    $('#featuredRecipe').append(randomRecipe);                  
               });

               //show similar product
               var categoryItems = [];
               $.each(json, function(i, item){
                      if(item.itemCommodity == '1120' && item.itemBrandLetter == "C") categoryItems.push(item);
                      if(item.itemCommodity == '2120' && item.itemBrandLetter == "C") categoryItems.push(item);
               });

               var similarProduct= '';
               $.each(json, function(i,item){
                  similarProduct = categoryItems[Math.floor(Math.random()*categoryItems.length)];
                  similarProduct += '<div>' + '<a href="#" class="showProduct"' + '>' + '<img class="img-responsive img-hover similarProductImagesCategory" src="' + similarProduct.imageURL + '">' + '<h3 class="similarProductSubCategoryImgCaption">' + similarProduct.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
               });
               $('#productSimilar').append(similarProduct);            
          });    
          closeNav();
      }

   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work. I was able to add the function to the body on click method and pass in all the data from the href. Works!